# Is this on fath al bari?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, hijab

i tried to find this text on fath al bari but couldn't so please anyone if can verify if this text really exist in fath al bari?

2.2 Sayyidah Āishah (May Allah be pleased with her) said, “A woman would lower her jilbāb over
her head onto her face.”
(Fatḥ al-Bārī 3:406)

The main article : https://bukhari2013.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/niqab-8-2.pdf

Comment: Would you mind sharing your source of the quote? And further information! The hadith is quoted at least in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1833). Further a similar narration appears in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4759) and therefore should be covered in Fath al-Bary.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I have updated my question. Also thank you for the post but i also want to know that the two hadith you have shown, can these be used as a prove that niqab  is mandatory?

Comment: @Medi1Saif i understand one hadith is daif but what about the other one. that indicates niqab is mandatory

Comment: @Yusha that would be a totally separate question.

Comment: @aadil095 i like to hear a answer here, if the answer is short. Because many claim that there is no direct hadith that shows niqab is compulsory.

Comment: The hadith from Sunan abi Dawod -if valid- would be an issue, because niqaab is at least makrooh while wearing Ihraam or praying. Therefore the majority view -which considers it haram- comes to the conclusion that it can't be sane.

Comment: @Medi1Saif What about the hadith of bukhari?

Comment: @Yusha it doesn't apply explicitly for the topic of niqab, but certainly is sahih.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is in Fath al-Bari, [Vol 3 Page 406](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1673/2064):

> عن عائشة قالت تسدل المرأة جلبابها من فوق رأسها على وجهها

Comment: can this be used as to proof that niqab is compulsory to wear?